# How to find open ports on localhost using telnetlib python?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I want to find all the ports that are open on my localhost using telnet.
I have set up a server using sockets on port 1234.
I am using the following code to check whether a port is open or not

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
for port in range (1,65535):
    try:
        if(telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,port)):
            print(port)
    except ConnectionRefusedError as err:
        print("connection refused")
```

However I get no output when I run this code.
Appreciate any corrections in the code.Thanks

Comment: 1-65535 = -65534 (look at "range" usage)

Have nice day

Comment: yes thank you i have corrected this small mistake.However the problem still persists I am trying to telnet to each port on the IP to find which ports are open.

Comment: That's wierd, it works for me. I just needed to remove this nasty "print("connection refused")" which was spamming nonsense (I replaced it with "pass"), now I see only open ports ;)

Comment: Ok it seems to be working now. I just restarted sublime text and it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Arguments passed to a function should be delimited by a comma, not a dash:

```
for port in range(1, 65536):
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the exception handling line without assigning the exception to a variable such below.

```
except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("connection refused")
```

It worked for me without any error.